# Updating to iOS 6.1 disables cellular FaceTime?

Tags: iphone, ios, facetime, cellular-carriers

FaceTime over AT&T's 4G (you know, 3G) on my iPhone 4s (with a 2GB data plan) was enabled as of a few days ago. Haven't checked the settings since then, but I just updated to iOS 6.1 from 6.0.1, and after a message came up about saying that the iPhone was now using the new iCloud email address for iMessages, I decided to check on FaceTime, and it appears that the cellular data option for FaceTime is switched off again (and I can't enable it, just shows the 'call AT&T' popup). I don't really know for sure if I can blame iOS 6.1 because as its been a few days since I checked the setting it could be coincidence.

What do you think? A glitch in AT&T's system that accidentally temporarily enabled my 4G FaceTime? Something about the update turning it off? When I asked AT&T, they were surprised that it was even working at all a few days ago.

Comment: The same thing happens on an iPhone 5. Mine has a grandfathered unlimited plan that worked with FaceTime over LTE (this was a reason for purchasing the 5, in fact), but since upgrading (which changed my caller ID for iMessage and FT too) LTE FaceTime is disabled.

Comment: Can anybody else confirm this or figure out a way to turn it back (like would changing caller ID settings work?)?

Comment: you have to wait AT&T to update its cellular settings.

Comment: Have you tried restoring?

Comment: I have only tried disabling @icloud.com in FaceTime. I'd rather not go through the hassle unless someone else already knows that it would be a solution.

Comment: Are you on an unlimited plan, or a tiered plan?  As of Jan. 16, those on unlimited plans are blocked from using FaceTime over cellular.  They just recently enabled it for tiered non-Mobile Share plans.  http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/01/att-continues-chipping-at-facetime-over-cellular-policy/

Comment: @WarrenPena, they mentioned they are on the 2GB tiered data plan.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in AT&T's blog post they said it would take several months to roll out, but sure enough, it says that.  Source: http://blogs.att.net/consumerblog/story/a7786791  It still seems strange to me that it was enabled for you, and now it is not.

Comment: So I contacted them again, and they said that before they officially began the rollout they accidentally turned it on for some people and then off. So, I guess that's just it. :( Gotta wait.

Comment: Update: FaceTime over cellular has been re-enabled. Hopefully for good this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to AT&T, before they officially began turning them on, some devices accidentally were switched on and then they turned them off, and that the actual rollout will be over a few months.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't exactly iOS 6.1 and it sounds like AT&T at it again. I updated my iPhone 4S to iOS 6.1 yesterday as well and my Facetime over Cellular is still enabled. I am on a shared data plan, though, which has always - since iOS 6.0 - had the option to Facetime over Cellular.

I think AT&T's response when you asked them shows who is ultimately at fault here. Even though 6.1 isn't exactly at fault, it is possible that AT&T hasn't fully opened the possibility to Facetime over cellular to users with data packages like yours, and that upgrading to iOS 6 somehow re-instated that until AT&T does better opening it up.

Comment: I'm giving you the bounty since, well, you're the only one who I can give it to. And you were close. According to AT&T it wasn't the upgrade that triggered it, so I guess that was a coincidence, but that they accidentally turned it on, and then turned it off, before they "officially" started the "rollout".

Comment: Thanks, @AL. When I saw the bounty on this question I started to look into it again. But I didn't get very far as I don't have access to a tiered data plan iPhone. If they haven't already got cellular FaceTime going, I hope they do quickly. Either way, I'm glad you got it figured out.